# How to create token for stripe with nodejs

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I can use `load-stripe` to generate a token on the front-end reactjs.

Now I need to do same thing on the backend nodejs. The user will pass `accountNumber` `cvv` and other information to the backend then how can I create a token using it?

Any help would be much appreciated
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NPM package stripe-node](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node)

```
var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc");

stripe.tokens.create({
  card: {
    "number": '4242424242424242',
    "exp_month": 12,
    "exp_year": 2019,
    "cvc": '123'
  }
}, function(err, token) {
  // asynchronously called
});
```

For more info: [Stripe Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_card?lang=node)

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend using `load-stripe` npm module

3 years have passed since last changes were made.

There is a good example of using stripe API on backend side without any dependencies at all.

https://github.com/olegdovger/pizza-delivery-api